# $A$ be a basis for a topology on $X$, and $\tau_X$ be a topology on $X$ s.t $A \subseteq \tau_X$. Then can we complete $A$ to a basis of $\tau_X$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be a basis for a topology on $X$, and let $\tau_X$ be a
topology on $X$ such that $A \subseteq \tau_X$. Then can we complete $A$ to a basis of $\tau_X$ ? (i.e there exists a basis $B$ of $\tau_X$ s.t $A \subseteq B$)

If so, how ? I mean is there any general procedure ? If not, how can we prove that is it always not possible, i.e can you provide a counterexample ?

Comment: What do you mean by "complete $A$ to a basis of $\tau_X$? What does "complete" mean here? Are you just asking if there is a basis $B$ of $\tau_X$ such that $A\subseteq B$? If that's the question, then an obvious answer is yes, let $B=\tau_X.$ So that can't be what you're asking.

Comment: @bof Actually, that is my question, but any basis of $\tau_X$ does not have to contain $A$ as a subset, is it ?

Comment: True, not every basis of $\tau_X$ contains $A$ as a subset, but some of them do. Is your question "does some basis of $\tau_x$ contain $A$" or is it "does every basis of $\tau_X$ contain $A$?

Comment: @bof the one with "some". Then how can we prove this fact ?

Comment: I just told you. Let $B=\tau_X.$ Then $B$ is some basis of $\tau_X,$ and $A\subseteq B.$

Comment: More generally, let $B_0$ be any basis of $\tau_X,$ Then $B=A\cup B_0$ is a basis of $\tau_X$ and $A\subseteq B.$

Comment: @bof Ok, thanks for your responses.